# SSRS 2008 Columns Toggling

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, toggle, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I have created a standard table with about 15 columns in it. The table has only 1 group being the Details row group as it a pretty simple table. The thing I am having trouble with is toggling the last 5 columns, I want them to be hidden by default and only available by selecting a + icon. I would also like all 5 to be displayed by selecting the 1 + icon so once the icon has been selected all 5 appear rather than 1 + icon per column (5).

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Highlight the first column you want to have toggled and right click. Select Column Visibility from the select list. The click on Hide and click the Display Can Be Toggled By This Report Item checkbox. Select the report item that you want to click on to toggle the columns. Go through each column one by one and do the same thing. If you select the same report item to toggle by for each column, clicking the report item will reveal all of them.

Comment: I thought I had tried this and got a scope error but think I must've been setting textbox visibility rather than column visibility. Thanks :)